# stuck on trying to implement KeyListener

Tags: java, swing, coding-style, jpanel, keylistener

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to make my code move a player (Ship) around a screen. I can get the planets to draw on the screen and the the player ship but I can not figure out how to implement the keyListener to at least print out something. Thank you in advance for all the help!

```
   import javax.swing.JFrame;
   import javax.swing.JPanel;
   import java.awt.Canvas;
   import java.awt.Color;
   import java.awt.Dimension;
   import java.awt.Graphics;
   import java.awt.Point;
   import java.awt.Toolkit;
   import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
   import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
   import java.awt.event.KeyListener;


  public class MapPanel extends JPanel {
  public static final int WIDTH = 25;
  public static final int HEIGHT = 20;
  int zone = 0;
  private int xValue;
  private int yValue;
  private Color color;
  public Planet[][] planetGrid = new Planet[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
  static Player currPlayer = new Player("h");
  static Universe universe = new Universe(currPlayer);

  /**
  * Create the panel.
  */
  public MapPanel(Universe univ, Player p) {
 this.universe = univ;
 currPlayer = p;
 int i = 0;
 this.setSize(new Dimension(450,450));
 setVisible( true );
 //this.addKeyListener(new KeyController());
 KeyController kc = new KeyController();
 this.addKeyListener(kc);
 repaint();


  }


  /**
  * Draw method to draw the playing field
  * @param g Graphics object
  * @param tileDimension dimension of the tile
  */
   public void draw(Graphics g)
   {
    universe.draw(g);

  //    KeyController key = new KeyController();
  }
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponent(g);
  draw(g);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    MapPanel mp = new MapPanel(universe, currPlayer);
   JFrame f = new JFrame();
   f.add(mp);
   f.setSize(new Dimension(450,450));
   f.setVisible(true);
   f.setFocusable(true);


    }
    private class KeyController implements KeyListener {
    public KeyController()
    {
     System.out.println("ghgh");
     setFocusable(true);
    // addKeyListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(final KeyEvent key) {
        System.out.println("fgfgf");
        if (currPlayer != null) {

            int oldX = currPlayer.getPosition().x;
            int oldY = currPlayer.getPosition().y;

            switch (key.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                  currPlayer.setPosition(new Point(oldX+1, oldY)); //move right
                  System.out.println("RIGHT");
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                      currPlayer.setPosition(new Point(oldX-1, oldY));         //move             left
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                      currPlayer.setPosition(new Point(oldX, oldY+1));         //move           down
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                      currPlayer.setPosition(new Point(oldX, oldY-1));         //move up
                    break;
            }

          }
          repaint();
        }
       @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("ggg");
    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("typeeeddd");
    }
     }





   }
```

Comment: 1) I removed the [tag:homework] tag since it has been made obsolete.  If you are after tips rather than a complete solution (better for learning), mention that in the question. 2) Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. 3) There is never need for more than one blank line in source to add 'white space'.

Comment: ..4) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: sorry about that, I usually find what i am looking for on here but rarely post anything

Comment: you don't want to use keyListeners at all, you want to use keyBindings (see the tutorial referenced in the swing tag wiki) - they are just perfect for your context.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Key Listener not working when being pressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113922/key-listener-not-working-when-being-pressed)

Comment: why do you ask the same question again (in such short succession)? stick to the first and try to digest the answer/s you get there. Ask a different question only if you have a ... _different_ problem.

Answer (score 0):

A `JPanel` won't get its keyboard focus automatically, you should call this, in the constructor:

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt){
        requestFocus();
    }
});
```

Comment: *"you should call `mp.requestFocus()`"*  No you shouldn't.  The docs. state *"Note that the use of this method is discouraged because its behavior is platform dependent. Instead we recommend the use of `requestFocusInWindow()`."*  Also a component will not be able to receive key events if it is not focusable (the default for panels).

Comment: So should I add requestFocusInWindow() into my contructor?

Comment: I want to take out my main method since I will be connecting this panel to other panels, it works if I add requestFocusInWindow() inside my main method but when I comment it out,  but still have it in my contructor, it stops working. What is the alternative to this so it can be in the constructor? thanks!

Comment: *"So should I add requestFocusInWindow() into my contructor?"*  No.  As it states in the Java Docs you should book mark .. *"This component must be displayable, focusable, visible and all of its ancestors (with the exception of the top-level Window) must be visible for the request to be granted."*  Read the rest of the [Java Docs for that method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocusInWindow%28%29) before asking further questions.  I expect the answer to your next question will be in those docs or the linked article.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to do

```
MapPanel panel = new MapPanel();
panel.setFocusable(true);
```

I was having the same problem, and I had to do for all the other components (such as JButton's) the following:

```
myButton.setFocusable(false);
```

Worked for me.